# How/where to get the ssh keys used when creating an aks cluster with "--generate-ssh-keys" option

Tags: azure, kubernetes, containers

We have created a AKS cluster using `az aks create .... --generate-ssh-keys ....`.
How/where can we find the SSH keys that were generated, so we can use them?
Thankx

Comment: it is in kube_config client_key base64 encoded if import cluster into  terraform as data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the SSH keys from the output of this command `az aks create .... --generate-ssh-keys`.

After you run this command, you can find your ssh key in that output.

[image]

You can find it in this path:

[image]

---

If you are use Linux, you can find it here:

[image]

> so we can use them?

You can use that SSH key to login AKS agent:

`ssh azureuser@52.170.1.* -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Thx. Does this mean that if the files already existed, they were used when creating the cluster?

Comment: @JoaoCC you are right

Comment: Do i get it right that `--generate-ssh-keys` is just a short hand for a local `ssh-keygen`? Is the public key also ingested into Azure? If so, where can I view and manage it in the Azure Portal?